# Spark custom serializer leads to ClassNotFound

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, spark-streaming, oozie

I'm trying to use **custom spark serializer** defined as:

conf.set("spark.serializer", CustomSparkSerializer.class.getCanonicalName());

But when I submit application to Spark I'm facing issue with **ClassNotFoundException** when executor env creating, for example:

16/04/01 18:41:11 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'sparkExecutor' on port 52153.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1643)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:149)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:250)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.CustomSparkSerializer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
        at **org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:173)**
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.instantiateClass$1(SparkEnv.scala:266)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.instantiateClassFromConf$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:290)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createExecutorEnv(SparkEnv.scala:218)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:183)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:69)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:68)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
```

In local standalone mode it can be solved using "**spark.executor.extraClassPath=path/to/jar**", but on cluster with several nodes it does not help.

I have tried all known (for me) approaches as such as use --jars, executor (and even driver) extra class and library path, sc.addJar also... It was not help.

I found that Spark uses *specific* classloader in   org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.classForName(Utils.scala:173) for load serializer class, but I really don't understand how to make custom serializer loadable.

The application flow submit is more complex - **Oozie -> SparkSubmit -> YARN client -> Spark application**

**The question is - does anybody know how to use custom spark serializer and how to resolve ClassNotFound issue with it ?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sent question to spark users mail list http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Spark-custom-serializer-leads-to-ClassNotFound-td26692.html

Comment: If you manually put the jar on the workers, does it work? I'm not sure this issue is specific to the custom serializer, seems broader to me.

Comment: Yuval, you are right, seems it's issue with ClassLoaders/classpath. After spent some time I found the following:

Comment: could you put your `spark-submit`  command that you use?

Comment: **Oozie** Spark action configuration: 
     **--master  yarn-client**   --name    Example-App   --class   com.example.Job
     --driver-memory  1g  --executor-memory 1g  --num-executors   4  --executor-cores  2
     --jars  hdfs://some_host:9000/user/${wf:user()}/project/lib/project-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
     **--conf  spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/some_user/project/project-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar**
     --verbose  hdfs://some_host:9000/user/some_user/project/lib/project-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it happens is because I use spark.executor.extraClassPath with prefix **/home/some_user**. It seems that Spark can not load any class from that path because Spark process owner is another user, once I putted JAR to path smth like **/usr/lib/** everything works fine.

So, I confused with users and Hadoop/Oozie/Spark processes owners, but I was not expecting such behavior from ClassLoaders =)

Thank you for help!